# prove that $2n^2, 2n^2+1$ and $2n^2 + 2$ can be written as sum of two squares

Tags: number-theory

Let $n=k(k+1)$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $2n^2, 2n^2 + 1$ and $2n^2 + 2$ can be written as sum of two squares.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your efforts

Comment: [hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem)

Comment: I could just prove for 2n^2 = n^2 + n^2, I have no idea about the rest

Comment: @Igracx33 What is your background? Do you have available the theorem that characterises the numbers that are sums of two squares (as in the link Don Thousand gave)? Or do you need to use an elementary method?

Comment: Note by the way that only $2n^2+1$ requires the assumption $n=k(k+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $2n^2$ can be written as the sum of two squares.

For $2n^2+1$ note that
$$
2n^2+1=2k^2(k+1)^2+1 = 2k^4+4k^3+2k^2+1 = (k^2+2k)^2+(k^2-1)^2.
$$

Finally, for $2n^2+2$ we just have

$$
2n^2+2=(n+1)^2+(n-1)^2.
$$